# Constructing large applications using React and react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Could any one please suggest how using react and react redux, can we create a big enterprise application , where routing to different urls of third party applications or other Single page Applications is involved?

Like for E.g. If we want to have Login as one different SPA but the main application as the other SPA rendering required views based upon the logged in user's access.

I went through the following links, suggesting use of windows.location and a href to go to urls of third party application, or using shared object between two different SPAs.

1) https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1434 
2) [React architecture for a huge business application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167555/react-architecture-for-a-huge-business-application)

Could anyone explain with some code snippet how we can handle two SPA interaction using React and react redux.